# Web Service Port No Question

Tags: web-services, apache, tcp, gsoap

I am working on a web service project using gsoap. I am new to web services and have some basic questions.

What should be the port no. of my web service? Currently this web service is a stand alone service listening to a hard-coded port no. of 22050. Client connects to this port and everything works fine. Is this approach OK? What are the pros/cons of this approach?

Or Should my web service be a plug-in of the apache web server? In that case how does it work? Apache httpd listens on port 80, so client sends request to this port. Then how does the request get routed to my web service?

I didn't find any proper online resources on these. Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to configure apache such that it knows it will be your web service. In this case you will probably give it a location. So you can configure a  directive that will make sure your service is called by apache.

I.e. you will use urls that identify your service (http://.

You will then use a location directive  in which you make the proper configurations. You can find more information at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html

Hope this helps.